# Why i get error in sql server ROW_NUMBER()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I'm new to SQL Server and write this query:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY TelNo ) as RowNum,
        Telno  
FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills]
where RowNum=1
```

When I run that query, I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>
> Invalid column name 'RowNum'.

How can i solve that?

thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't filter a ranking function result in the same `select` statement.
Use the below script.

```
with cte_1
as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY TelNo ) as RowNum,Telno  FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills])
SELECT *
FROM cte_1
where RowNum=1
```

Comment: thanks for answer,after 11 minute accept your answer

Comment: Thank you.. give an up-vote also if you agree with this answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way,

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY TelNo ) as RowNum, Telno  
        FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills]
     ) AS tbl
WHERE RowNum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you cannot use computed column allias in WHERE statement, or even put `where ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY TelNo ) = 1` because it is forbidden.

You dint need to use CTE or sub-query's, just use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` with ordering by `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Telno  
FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills]
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY TelNo)
```